# How to add Image field on right side in bootstrap form

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have an bootstrap form with 9 input field.I have applied 3 field in each row which looks as responsive.I would like to know how to add image field on right side and which should be span of three row.please check my below code and advise how to align the image control as right side.

updated code version 3.0.0:-

```
      <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-sm-1  col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="text" name="FirstName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName"
                     placeholder="First Name" value={ this.state.FirstName } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="text" name="LastName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtLastName"
                     placeholder="Last Name" value={ this.state.LastName } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email Id</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="email" name="EmailId" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtEmailId"
                     placeholder="EmailId" value={ this.state.EmailId } required onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Mobile No</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="text" name="MobileNo" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtMobileNo"
                     placeholder="Mobile No" value={ this.state.MobileNo } onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Division</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <select name="DivisionId" className="form-control" required value={ this.state.DivisionId }
                      onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }>
                { DivisionList }
              </select>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">User Name</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="text" name="UserName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtUserName"
                     placeholder="User Name" value={ this.state.UserName } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Password</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="password" name="DPassword" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtPassword"
                     placeholder="Password" value={ this.state.DPassword } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Confirm</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" className="form-control form-control-sm"
                     id="TxtConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required value={ this.state.ConfirmPassword }
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Role</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3 pl-0">
              <select name="RoleId" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"
                      className="form-control selectpicker" id="CboRole" value={ this.state.RoleId } required
                      onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }>
                { RoleList }
              </select>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-2">
        <img className='img-fluid' src={ users } alt='Alt text'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

screenshot :-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many cols do you want your image to take, but what you can do is the following: Wrap your code in a new **Row**. Then divide it into as many columns as you want (for the example I have divided it 50:50 - 50% of the screen will be filled with your inputs and 50% with the image) - you can configure this by yourself. Try the following and let me know if this is what you seek:

```
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="FirstName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName"
                     placeholder="First Name" value={ this.state.FirstName } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="LastName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtLastName"
                     placeholder="Last Name" value={ this.state.LastName } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email Id</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="email" name="EmailId" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtEmailId"
                     placeholder="EmailId" value={ this.state.EmailId } required onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Mobile No</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="MobileNo" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtMobileNo"
                     placeholder="Mobile No" value={ this.state.MobileNo } onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Division</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <select name="DivisionId" className="form-control" required value={ this.state.DivisionId }
                      onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }>
                { DivisionList }
              </select>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">User Name</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="UserName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtUserName"
                     placeholder="User Name" value={ this.state.UserName } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Password</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="password" name="DPassword" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtPassword"
                     placeholder="Password" value={ this.state.DPassword } required
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Confirm</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" className="form-control form-control-sm"
                     id="TxtConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required value={ this.state.ConfirmPassword }
                     onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }/>
            </div>

            <label className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Role</label>
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <select name="RoleId" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"
                      className="form-control selectpicker" id="CboRole" value={ this.state.RoleId } required
                      onChange={ this.onChangeHandler }>
                { RoleList }
              </select>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <img className='img-fluid' src={ path } alt='Alt text'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's because you need to wrap the rows in a container-fluid, because the row has negative margin right and left, but the container is giving padding. Also consider using the class 'img-fluid' for the image, so it always fits in your screen. I updated my answer

Comment: sorry ,i have updated version 2.0 code but still same issue

Comment: That is weird.. I tested it out and it worked perfectly. Are you sure that you applied containers everywhere, and also added the `img-fluid` class to the image? Also which version of bootstrap are you using? Because if you use Bootstrap 3.x, the class is called `img-responsive`

Comment: thanks , i have solved my problem but there is an alignment issue in label land input control,please check updated screenshot and source code as version 3.0

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap` It will leave your labels to a single line, but they will probably overlap with your inputs. Or is there another problem that I didn't notice?

Comment: Leave more space to the labels and use `white-space: nowrap` property on the labels

Comment: I have solved my problem by changing class as  <div className="container-fluid p-1">